# How to check validation on creation method if its called from specific route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, rails-activerecord, rails-routing

I want to validate column presence on creation method if the creation method is called from some other route.
For example, If I have following two routes:

```
post 'create_item', to: 'item#create'
post 'create_verified_item', to: 'item#create_verified'
```

I need to define in Item model something like this:

```
validates :verified_number, presence: true, if: Item.action_name == "create_verified"
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally you can add a attribute to item to check that, something like:

```
# model
class Item
  attr_accessible :action_name

  validates :verified_number, presence: true, if: :create_verified?

  def create_verified?
    action_name == 'create_verified'
  end
end

# controller
item = Item.new(item_params)
item.action_name = params[:action]
item.save
```