# Rails 5: controller action in module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I realize this is against MVC principals and all, but how can I access the controller name/method in a module *that is included in a class*?

```
module DocumentHTMLBoxes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def icon_or_text(variable)
      if controller.action_name == 'send'
        "<b>#{variable.name.capitalize}</b> #{variable.text}\n"
      else
        variable.format!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I access `controller` and/or `controller.action_name` in the module?

Comment: please check my answer to get an idea to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46211747/how-to-check-validation-on-creation-method-if-its-called-from-specific-route/46212294#46212294

Comment: You should update the question to reflect that you are trying to include this in a model as indicated by your comments on an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Rails the `view_context` object contains all the ivars from the controller and includes all the helpers. It also provides access to the session, cookies and request. It is the implicit `self` when you are rendering templates.

Models do not have access to the view context - this is a conscious design as it gives a good seperation of concerns.

If you want to break the encapsulation you need to pass the context to the model.

```
module DocumentHTMLBoxes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def icon_or_text(variable, context)
      if context.action_name == 'send'
        "<b>#{variable.name.capitalize}</b> #{variable.text}\n"
      else
        variable.format!
      end
    end
  end
end

class Thing < ApplicationModel
  include DocumentHTMLBoxes
end
```

Congratulations, you just created some really smelly code.

But, this is a really bad idea since it just adds one more responsibility to your models which are already near god-class status in Rails. Don't add generating HTML (a view/helper responsiblity!) to that list.

Instead you should just create a simple helper method:

```
module BoxesHelper
  def icon_or_text(obj)
    if context.action_name == 'send'
      "<b>#{obj.name.capitalize}</b> #{obj.text}\n"
    else
      obj.format!
    end
  end
end
```

Or a [decorator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern):

```
# @see https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/delegate/rdoc/Delegator.html
class Decorator < Delegator
  attr_accessor :object
  attr_accessor :context

  def intialize(obj, cxt)
    @object = obj
    @context = cxt
    super(obj) # pass obj to Delegator constructor, required
  end

  # Required by Delegator
  def __getobj__
    @object
  end

  def self.decorate(collection, context)
    return collection.map { |record| self.new(record, context) }
  end
end

module DocumentHTMLBoxes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def icon_or_text(variable)
      if context.action_name == 'send'
        "<b>#{object.name.capitalize}</b> #{object.text}\n"
      else
        object.format!
      end
    end
  end
end

class ThingDecorator < Decorator
  include DocumentHTMLBoxes
end
```

To decorate a bunch of records in the controller you would do:

```
@things = ThingDecorator.decorate( Thing.all, self.view_context )
```

And now you can call `icon_or_text` on the decorated model:

```
<% @things.each do |t| %>
  <% t.icon_or_text %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: On a side note - never name a variable "variable" unless you want to look like an idiot. Everyone gets that its a variable!

Comment: No - Rails is designed this way for a reason. @МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: If generating HTML in your models was encouraged the framework would provide access to the view context. @МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: Since rials have the concerns is it not, please show where rails authors say that such way is smelly

Comment: Agreed according model, but you don;t elaborate the problem at the beginning, just declarated that is smelly...

Comment: I really don't see how concerns changes that - they are just paving the cowpaths around module based horizontal inheritance. You can missuse them in any way you want. Just because its possible does not mean its a good idea. Also the "rails authors" may not have explicitly said that generating HTML in your models is evil but every missguided issue and PR to shoehorn the view context into models has been killed off. What more proof do you need? @МалъСкрылевъ

Comment: I'm going to accept this one since it's more in keeping with MVC logic despite the original request.

Answer (score 2):

I`d recommend refactor the code to make it cleaner:

1. Controller level call would be like

   ```
   model_item.icon_or_text(variable, action_name)
   ```
2. The module

   ```
   module DocumentHTMLBoxes
     extend ActiveSupport::Concern



     included do
       def icon_or_text(variable, action_name)
         if action_name == 'send'
           "<b>#{variable.name.capitalize}</b> #{variable.text}\n"
         else
           variable.format!
         end
       end
     end
   end
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are including this concern into the controller then inside the icon_or_text method self is the controller. You will just be able to call action_name without prefixing it with controller.

```
module DocumentHTMLBoxes
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    def icon_or_text(variable)
      if action_name == 'send'
        "<b>#{variable.name.capitalize}</b> #{variable.text}\n"
      else
        variable.format!
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have elaborated. This concern is included in a model.

Comment: If it is being included in a model, then the information has to be passed into the method. I might use a keyword argument such as
  `def icon_or_text(variable, html:)
      if html
        "<b>#{variable.name.capitalize}</b> #{variable.text}\n"
      else
        variable.format!
      end
  end
`

Then call it like so
`icon_or_text(variable, html: action_name == 'send')`